# How to add shadow to window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have removed the default borders around the primary stage:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)
```

This removes the window borders which is what I want, but now I'd like to have a drop shadow under the window.

The top level `BorderPane` object has a `dropshadow` effect applied, but the shadow is cut off:

[image]

You can see the shadow slightly on the bottom right, but as soon as the main application area ends the shadow is cut off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created an [example](https://gist.github.com/1887631/155d5e052b6ec7d0eaa6f825713f98f8e542152e) for this earlier.  Use the specific revision linked as in later revisions I dropped the shadow effect from the dialog.

The sample places the stage content in a StackPane containing two panes.  The shadow is only applied to the background Pane and the dialog content is placed in a top pane.  The background of the top pane is slightly inset from the bottom pane so that the background and shadow can show through.

Further discussion is in a thread on displaying a [shadow around an undecorated/transparent stage](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2432612).

[image: Sample shadowed dialog]